# do you say "to pour hard objects out of a container"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

> **[pour](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/pour?q=pour)** [transitive] to make a liquid or other substance flow from a container in a continuous stream, especially by holding the container
>   at an angle
>
> pour something + adv./prep. Pour the sauce over the pasta.
>
> She poured boiling water down the sink.
>
> Pour away as much fat as possible from the roasting pan.
>
> pour something Although I poured it carefully, I still managed to
>   spill some.
>
> The crew mixed and poured the concrete.

---

It seems like you use "**pour**" with liquid-form substances or grainy stuff such as water or milk or salt, etc.

I am not sure if it can be used with hard objects like toys or rocks or paper-form like money.

do you say "**to pour toys / rocks / dollars out of a bag**"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [Tip Out](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/tipped+out) - To empty a vessel of its contents by tipping it over. A noun or pronoun is used between "tip" and "out."

It's worth noting that, although less usual, you could also tip out a liquid.

You *can* pour out solid objects, especially if there are more than one (and therefore they would act like a liquid) but it's more of a metaphor.

For example:

> He poured out the contents of his coin purse onto the table.